# Can't createAnswer from peer

Tags: webrtc

I'm facing a problem where `createAnswer()` is not being called.

I'm looking for a way where a new user connects to the website and all other peers get an offer from the new peer and should create an answer. Where is my problem?

```
function onMessage (topic, event) {
    console.log(event);

    if(event.session_id == session._session_id)
      return;

    if(event.sdp) {

      console.log(event.sdp.type);
      if(event.type == "offer"){

        pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(event.sdp));

        pc.createAnswer(function(offer) {
          debugger;
          pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
          session.publish("http://example.com/webrtc", { session_id: session._session_id ,sdp: offer, type: offer.type});
        });
      }
    }

    if(event.candidate)
      pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
  }
```

For the signalling channel I use Web-sockets an the wamp protocol.

[I have deployed the application here,](https://play-webrtc.herokuapp.com/)
the [source code is available here](https://github.com/aBuder/play-webrtc/blob/master/public/js/main.js).

Comment: You should probably call `createAnswer` in the success call back of the `setRemoteDescription` call.

Comment: Is it possible, that you create an gist or sample code?

Comment: `peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(description, function () {
 peerConnection.createAnswer(function (desc) {
  //do what you want
  });
    },function(e){
  //handle an error
 });`

Comment: I get this error: "Failed to set remote offer sdp: Called in wrong state: STATE_SENTINITIATE" What is my mistake?

        pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(event.sdp),function(success){
          debugger;
          pc.createAnswer(pc.remoteDescription,function(offer) {
            pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
            session.publish("http://example.com/webrtc", { session_id: session._session_id ,sdp: offer, type: offer.type});
          });
        },function(error){
          debugger;
        });